# How to generate date in the format of credit/debit card expiry date?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date

I have a requirement of generating dates in this format `'Thru: 12/20'` (like credit/debit card expiry date format). What is the best way of generating date in this format?

```
new Date().toJSON().slice(0,7).split('-').reverse().join('/')
```

I got the date in mm/yyyy format but couldn't get the desired result

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: I don't know what the "best" way is, buy at least, what is _your_ way? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @JeremyThille,
```new Date().toJSON().slice(0,7).split('-').reverse().join('/')```
I got the date in mm/yyyy format but couldn't get the desired result

Comment: But the code you gave outputs '12/2021'. You're nearly there, you want '12/21', right? Just remove the extra '20'

Comment: No I need he day as well , like - 'Thru: 12/20'

Comment: random date is fine , just need the date in this format, removed random from question @LawrenceCherone

Comment: But Thru is not a day

Comment: y cant you try some regex ..here is an article on that https://www.w3spoint.com/credit-card-validation-javascript-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) to generate date in day name and dd/MM format

```js
const options = { weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' };
const result = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB', options).format(new Date());
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) you can simply do:

```js
const date = moment().format("ddd DD/MM");
console.log("Valid until : " + date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do this using Js only ?

Comment: Let's avoid recommending external libs in 2020+ when the browsers provide `Intl.DateTimeFormat`

Comment: As with any other JS written by other people, Moment is still JS … but I wouldn't recommend using it today: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: I've tried Luxon, I don't like it. It's harder to use than Moment and takes much of the easy syntax away. I think I'll keep using good ol'Moment as long as it works. Or as @AnthumChris said, just use `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.